# Why the pipe command "l | grep "1" " get the wrong result?

Tags: command-line, grep, ls, pipe

As the picture illustrates, I use `l` to get the file in the current folder. And then I want to get the file with number `1`, so I use the `pipe` and the `grep`.

But why the `2` and `22` file show out? And what is the `1;34m`?

```
$ l
./ ../ 1 11 2 22
$ l | grep "1"
1;34m./ 1;32m../ 1 11 2 22
```

---

**Update**

I have already alias the command `l` in my `zshrc` file.

```
 alias lsp="ls"
 alias ll='ls -alF'
 alias la='ls -A'
 alias l='ls -CF'
 alias ls="ls -alh --color"
```

And here is the result of the `type` command:

```
>$ type ls
ls is an alias for ls -alh --color

> $ type l
l is an alias for ls -CF
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: @muru I think you meant to ask post output of `type -a l`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix ah, yes.

Comment: @Lee may I ask you to post output of `type ls` command please ?  have you modified `ls` alias in any way ?

Comment: @Serg already updated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all, what you're trying to do , `l| grep <filename>` is bad. Don't do it. Here's why.

`l` command is really an alias to `ls -CF`

```
$ type -a l
l is aliased to `ls -CF'
```

By default in Ubuntu's `bash` , `ls` is an alias to `ls --color=auto`. As steeldriver pointed out in the comments `--color=auto` is supposed to turn off colorization. In your specific case , you have `alias ls="ls -alh --color"` and `alias l="ls -CF"` , which basically ends up being `ls -alh --color -CF`. This particular combination of switches still sends colorized output over a pipe. For example:

```
$ ls -alh --color -CF ~/TESTDIR | cat -A                                                                                 
^[[0m^[[01;34m.^[[0m/  ^[[01;34m..^[[0m/  1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  out.txt$
```

Notice how the `.` and `..` directories have same escape sequences.

#### What does this all mean

This means that `l` will output colorized list of files according to file type. Problem is that colorization happens with the use of [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence). That's what `1:34m` things are - they're escape sequence for specific colors.

The main problem is that parsing `ls` often leads to wrong output and disasters in scripts, simply because `ls` allows escape sequences like explained earlier and other special characters. See this article for more info: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

#### What you should be doing:

Use `find` command  :

```
bash-4.3$ ls
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  out.txt
bash-4.3$ find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*1*"
./1.txt
```

You could do something like this with shell glob and modern test `[[` command:

```
bash-4.3$ for file in * ;do if [[ "$file" =~ "1"  ]] ;then echo "$file" ;fi ; done
1.txt
```

Or maybe use python, which has far better filename handling capabilities than `bash` alone

```
bash-4.3$ python -c 'import os;print [f for f in os.listdir(".") if "1" in f ]'
['1.txt']
```

If there's no need to process the output of `ls` , simple globbing with `ls` can do the work, too. ( Remember, this is only for viewing list of files, not for passing it to another program to deal with the output text)

```
bash-4.3$ ls *1*
1.txt
```

Comment: I think the output will only be colorized *in a pipe* if `--color=always` is also specified - either as part of the alias for `l` or in a previous alias for `ls` itself (replacing the default `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`).

Comment: @steeldriver Good point, but isn't that's what `ls` in bash by default is ? `type ls` gives me that it's an alias for `ls --color=auto`

Comment: Yes that's the default - but `auto` turns off color in a pipe AFAIK. To be seeing ANSI color sequences, it must have been changed to `--color=always`, either in the `ls` alias or the `l` alias

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. That's very odd.

Comment: @steeldriver So I requested OP to post his aliases, and apparently what they have, namely `ls --color` , doesn't prevent colorization ( tested that myself , too). Updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 6):

#### Your `l` and `ls` commands are setup as aliases.

When you run them piping the output through `grep "1"` (using `|`) each screen line where `1` appears is displayed, with the `1` colored red.

Because file names `.`, `..`, `2` and `22` appear on the same screen line, they are output by `grep` as well but do not appear in red which shows `grep` matches.

The `:34m` is an escape sequence for a color that doesn't paint properly. Based on your revised question with the output of `type -a l` and `type -a` it can be reproduced in my system. Please note you should change your alias from `--color` to `--color=auto`:

#### Color output

[image: color ls]

Comment: The `1:34m` things aren't corruption, they're escape sequences used for colorization of text. See my answer on that  part ;)

Comment: @Serg Thank you. I've revised based on OP revised question with aliases.

Answer (score 1):

In your trial, you were calling your `ls` alias, thus the `1;34m` and similar noise which come from coloring, and since the pipe `|` receives all this on the same line, the `grep` matches the file `1` from that line and consequently prints this line. This is what you see on screen.

When you are doing stuff like that, it is always good to go back to the system command with 1 result per line.

To get rid of aliases just type `\ls`, and use the option `-1` to print results separated by line feeds.

```
$ \ls -1 | grep "1"
1
11
```

*Note: the backslash method works with every command, `\command` just calls the unaliased system command.*